# execute django raw querie using ilike sentence

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-orm

I got a query that compared with ORM is much more simpler using direct sql, Trying to execute it directly is in the part related to the ilike clause, I tried different ways but all fails

(added a shorter query just to exemplify the problem)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike '%%%s%%'", ["jan"])
cursor.execute("SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike %%%s%%", ["jan"])
cursor.execute("SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike %s", ["jan"])
cursor.execute("SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike '%%%s%%'", ["jan"])
```

the error:

```
LINE 1: SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike '%'jan'%'
LINE 1: SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike %'jan'%
LINE 1: SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike 'jan'
LINE 1: SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike '%'jan'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ilike` is equivalent to the [**`__iexact`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact):

```
Customer.objects.filter(name__iexact='jan')  # equivalent to name ILIKE jan
```

or if you want to look for a string that *contains* `'jan`', you can use [**`__icontains`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains):

```
Customer.objects.filter(name__icontains='jan')  # equivalent to name ILIKE '%jan%'
```

or if this is from another field, you can use an [**`F`**-expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F


Customer.objects.filter(name__icontains=F('fieldname'))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, although what I'm looking for is the right way to execute an ilike query having a variable

let's say,  "SELECT cc.name FROM customer cc WHERE name ilike '%{name}%'".

Comment: @CarlosRojas: in that case you can use an `F` expression if it is a fieldname. If you want to use a Python variable, it is `.filter(name__icontains=name)` with (the second) `name` the name of the variable..